# JSON.NET - exclude properties of a specific type at runtime

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization, json.net

I'm wondering **how to exclude/strip certain properties of given type(s) (or collections of those) from being serialized** using Json.NET library? 
I tried to write my own contract resolver (inheriting from *DefaultContractResolver*) with no luck.

I know that I could be done using DataAnnotations, decorating the excluded properties with **ScriptIgnoreAttribute**, but **it's not applicable** in my scenario. The objects serialized can be virtually anything, so I don't know which properties to exclude at design-time. I know only the **types** of properties that should not be serialized.

It looks like a rather simple task, but unfortunately I couldn't find a decent solution anywhere...

*BTW - **I'm not bound to Json.NET library** - if it can easily be done with default/other .NET JSON serializers it'd be an equally good solution for me.*

**UPDATE**

**The properties has to be excluded before trying to serialize them.** Why?

Basically, the types of objects I'm receiving and serializing can have dynamic properties of type inheriting from *IDynamicMetaObjectProvider*. I'm not going to describe all the details, but the *DynamicMetaObject* returned from *GetMetaObject* method of these objects doesn't have *DynamicMetaObject.GetDynamicMemberNames* method implemented (throws *NotImplementedException*...). **Summarizing - the problem is those objects (I need to exclude) doesn't allow to enumerate their properties**, what Json.NET serializer tries to do behind the scenes. I always end up with *NotImplementedException* being thrown.

Comment: So, to clarify, you want to exclude from serialization properties whose values implement `IDynamicMetaObjectProvider`?  I am very familiar  with dynamic types, but I am unsure in your case what you *are* actually serializing.  It sounds like you are serializing normal classes and want to exclude certain properties on these that reference dynamic instances.  At the same time you also indicated that you do not know the types, or base types, of the items you are serializing--just that they occasionally reference properties that are dynamic and cannot be serialized.  Please post a simple example.

Comment: Exactly that! The root object I'm serializing can be anything, but sometimes it may have a dynamic property (which references some IDynamicMetaObjectProvider object, or a collection of some), which I want to exclude from serialization. Serialized object is not dynamic, only the excluded property/ies are.

Comment: Is it sufficient to your need to not completely exclude these properties by instead to serialize them as empty objects?  So a property named Foo whose instance is dynamic would be serialized as Foo: {}

Comment: @Jamie: That'd be perfectly sufficient, yes. They are not going to be de-serialized to .NET objects, but only reused client-side in JS.

Comment: Do you know the type of the dynamic property values themselves?  For example, are they instances of `DynamicObject` or some other known type implementing `IDynamicMetaObjectProvider` or are they also completely random classes from other libraries not known at design time?

Comment: @Jamie: Yes, I know the exact types to exclude

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have tried both the WCF JSON serialization as well as the [System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx).  I have found if you want solid control of the serialization process and do not want to be bound by attributes and hacks to make things work, the `JavaScriptSerializer` is the way to go.  It is included in the .NET stack and allows you to create and register `JavaScriptConverter` subclasses to perform custom serialization of types.

The only restriction I have found that may cause you a problem is that you cannot easily register a converter to convert all subclasses of `Object` (aka, one converter to rule them all).  You really need to have knowledge of common base classes or preregister the set of types up front by scanning an assembly.  However, property serialization is entirely left up to you, so you can decide using simple reflection which properties to serialize and how.

Plus, the default serialization is much much much better for JSON than the WCF approach.  By default, all types are serializable without attributes, enums serialize by name, string-key dictionaries serialize as JSON objects, lists serialize as arrays, etc.  But for obvious reasons, such as circular trees, even the default behavior needs assistance from time to time.

In my case, I was supporting a client-API that did not exactly match the server class structure, and we wanted a much simpler JSON syntax that was easy on the eyes, and the `JavaScriptSerializer` did the trick every time.  Just let me know if you need some code samples to get started.

Comment: @Jamie: Thanks for the info, but unfortunately I cannot know the exact type of a *serialized* object at design time, as they can be just anything. I only know the exact types that *shouldn't be serialized*

Comment: Do you need to perform custom serialization for all types found in the .NET framework itself, or just types in your own projects or assemblies you are referencing.  If the later, you could easily register converters for all types in your assemblies (less exclusions of your choosing).  This could be as simple passing something like assembly.GetTypes().Where(t => t.IsClass) during the registration process.

Comment: @Jamie: Application has a modular structure, so assemblies from which the objects come can be added/removed at runtime. Btw it looks like an overkill to scan all assemblies and gather all types just to do simple JSON serialization.

Comment: Agreed.  I fortunately have not needed to resort to this approach.  However, that is my only frustration with the `JavaScriptSerializer` as it requires you to specify the supported types for a converter up front instead of allowing you to specify a predicate `Func<Type, bool>` to indicate support on the fly and then caching the result in an internal hashtable to not adversely affect performance.

Comment: Since you know the exact runtime types of the instances you want to avoid serializing, you can register a `JavaScriptConverter` that returns these types from the [SupportedTypes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptconverter.supportedtypes.aspx) property.  Then just override [Serialize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptconverter.serialize.aspx) in the converter and return an empty hashtable (or potentially null) indicating that you do not want to serialize anything.

Comment: @Jamie: That worked like a charm and was a rather an easy task, so many thanks for pointing me in this direction! I'll mark your answer as accepted ofc:)

Comment: @pszmyd: Awesome!  Glad it solved your problem.  Were you able to return null from `Serialize` or were you forced to return an empty `Hashtable`.  The docs do not specify, but the code makes it seems like it will work as long as you are not using a custom type resolver.

Answer (score 2):

Create your own contract resolver, override the method that creates the properties for an object and then filter the results to only include those that you want.

Comment: thanks for the tip. I've tried that, but couldn't get it to work as I need to exclude certain properties **before** serializer even tries to inspect them. Some of the dynamic objects I need to exclude doesn't allow to enumerate their members and throw an exception if you try. So filtering the results is not going to work... I've updated the question accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

Have you considered using the [ShouldSerialize](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2010/04/16/json-net-3-5-release-7-bson-binary-json-part-deux.aspx) prefix property to exclude the property of your specific type at runtime?

```
public class Employee
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public Employee Manager { get; set; }

  public bool ShouldSerializeManager()
  {
    return (Manager != this);
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, but unfortunately this did not address my issue. It was about not being able to choose certain properties (based on their type) of some arbitrary object (not known at design time) and exclude those from serialization. I knew only the types that shouldn't get serialized, nothing else.